# Local time of Brownian motion around the origin

Tags: probability, probability-theory, stochastic-processes, stochastic-calculus, brownian-motion

Consider the local time of a standard Brownian motion $L_t^a$ for $(t,a)\in\mathbb{R}_+\times\mathbb{R}$. Is the probability of the event
$$A:=\big\{ \text{There exists a neighborhood } N \text{ of } (0,0) \text{ such that } L_t^a>0 \text{ for } (t,a)\in N \text{ with } t>0\big\}$$
greater than zero? I haven't been able to characterize the behavior of $L_t^a$ in $a$ and $t$ jointly around the origin...

Comment: Please tell me if I interpret your question wrong. First of all $N$ cannot contain $(0,0)$ as $L_0^0$ is not positive. Furthermore you cannot give yourself some $\varepsilon$ such that $L_t^a>0$ for all $t>0$ and $a \in (-\varepsilon,\varepsilon)$ due to continuity of the Brownian paths. Maybe the following helps you to reformulate what you want: The local time at zero and the maximum process of a Bm are equal in distribution and therefore $L_t^0>0$ for all $t>0$ almost surely. (see Theorem 6.10 in the book "Brownian Motion" by Moerters  and Peres)

Comment: @lukanz Thanks! Indeed, I realize now that the question is ill-formulated. I know this theorem, but I would to know something about $L_t^a$ in both variables. Ideally, $L_t^a$ would be nonzero on $N$ for $t\neq 0$ for example. I have edited my question to reflect this.

Comment: I still do not think this is what you want as $N$ has to contain some $B_\varepsilon := \{(t,a) \in \mathbb{R}_+ \times \mathbb{R}:t<\varepsilon, |a|<\varepsilon\}$ and therefore $L_t^a>0$ for $(t,a) \in B_\varepsilon$. This is not possible as by continuity we can choose some $\delta \in (0,\varepsilon)$ such that $|B_t|<\varepsilon/2$ for $t\in (0,\delta)$ and therefore $L_t^a=0$ for $(t,a)$ with $t\in (0,\delta)$ and $|a| \in (\varepsilon/2,\varepsilon)$.

Comment: @lukanz actually this is exactly the answer that I wanted :) For some reason, I thought that $N$ would exit, but it doesn't. Thanks a lot!